# how to increase timeout on remote desktop interactive logon message

Tags: remote-desktop

When I remote into a server, I get a message and have to click ok before the desktop will load. If I don't click ok after a few minutes, the remote desktop session goes away and I have to go through the connection process again. Is there a way to increase the timeout on that to more like an hour?
The message is from Group Policy setting - Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on
The OS is any version of Windows connecting to Windows Server ( 2008R2/2012R2/2016).
I am using mRemoteNG as the remote desktop client, but I think it is the same regardless of client. So, I'm guessing the timeout is on the server side.

Comment: There are many remote desktop applications, which one are you using? On what OS?

Comment: We don't know what message you're referring to, but presumably you mean this setting: `Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on`. If so, I'm not aware of a method to change the timeout. Why do you need it to be set to more than an hour? Why don't you respond to it when you log on?

Comment: Thanks. I added those details. I constantly have to connect to servers throughout the day. I might have 12 tabs of servers open and am trying to open all of them. It can take a while to connect; so, I want to move on and sometimes I forget to come back immediately. Also, if rebooting, the application can automatically reconnect and logon, but it will get hung up here. It's just really annoying to always get stopped and so often kicked back out. I would remove this message policy altogether except someone decided that it needs to be there and I don't have authority to make that decision.